# Time constraint to complete a task

Tags: bpmn

I was wondering if there is a standard notation to say for example: This task has to be completed within 2 days from the moment it has been assigned? I found a bunch of information with regards to timers, but I can't see how to integrate the timer element here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it depends on whether you want to consider the case of a task being not completed in the time span or not.

For the first case, so when the time constraint should only be of informative value, you can simply create an attribute on task level (call it e.g. "time limit" and add the respective values to the attribute.

For the second case, you could add a parallel gateway before the task and add a catching intermediate timer event, which is triggered when the time constraint is exceeded, parallel to the task. The timer event can then trigger a check for the execution state of the task.

I suppose there is no standard notation, as it strongly depends on the process scenario if, how and by whom the time constraint should be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've opted for the first option (attribute) since it's only informative and the "timer" won't trigger anything.